# Windows 10 workgroup drive nore longer visible

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares

I had a Workgroup (not homegroup) set up on Windows 10, with shared network drives.

Now the drives are no longer visible, and - I swear - I didn't change anything (yeah, I Know :-).

I am guessing that some Windows update has changed things.

I have a desktop, which I only use as a backup server, and can no longer see its dries.

I have Googled for a few days, and suspect the problem might be that the desktop has no password. I would prefer not to have one, but if I have no choice, then ...

I tried to add a password, but Widows would not accept blank as current password, so I cannot set one.

I would be happy if anyone can help.

I would be equally happy for an alternative solution, so long as it is simple to set up & I won't have to lose more days trying to configure it.

I am considering a Samba server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did not use a homegroup at all.

I deleted my homegroup completely, as shown [here](http://windowsreport.com/remove-homegroup-windows-10/).

Then, after reboot, I found that I ***could*** add a password. I am to 100% if that is necessary, but I was still trying to set up a homegroup at the time.

I simply right-clicked the desired folders & chose "sharing", and shared the drives to the network.

After that, on the laptop, I just have to open Explorer, go to "network", click "server" and enter then login details of the server, and I can share its drives from my laptop.

Hope this helps someone.